# How do we execute load test in cassandra DB using JMeter 5.1. Is there any plugins available?

Tags: cassandra, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to do load testing on cassandra DB. But when I check for JMeter cassandra pluggins there are 7 Cassandra Samplers in JMeter while using JMeter Pluggins installation. I have pretty good idea of the servers, keyspaces and connection

There is limited help in this regard and when searched for it is with the JMeter 2.9 versions.

Answer (score 0):

Just like any other database (given it supports [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) protocol)

1. Download [Cassandra JDBC Driver](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.cassandra/cassandra-driver-core/3.3.0) (with all the dependencies) and drop it to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. Restart JMeter to pick the libraries up
3. Add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to your Test Plan
4. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def cluster = com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.builder().addContactPoint("IP Address or hostname of your Cassandra cluster").build();
   def session = cluster.connect("your space");

   def results = session.execute("SELECT * FROM users");

   session.close();
   cluster.close();
   ```

More information: [Cassandra Load Testing with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/cassandra-load-testing-with-groovy/)

Comment: is it possible to test without creating the session every time?

Answer (score -1):

It would be better that you use the `cassandra-stress tool` for this purpose. There are several resources available; as a starting point, you can look at [datastax-academy](https://academy.datastax.com/units/2104-cassandra-stress-dse-operations-apache-cassandra) or [the last pickle blog.](https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2017/02/08/Modeling-real-life-workloads-with-cassandra-stress.html)

Comment: it is very limited, doesn't support the map type, for example